# How to work around the limitation of `len` function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

The `len` builtin function in `Python` is limited to the system's integer length. So, in my case, it is limited to `sys.maxsize` which is **2147483647**. However, the in light with the `Python3`'s unlimited integer, I think this limitation is causing frustration. Is there any workarounds to overcome this limitation? For example, I would like to get the length of this:

```
range(3, 100000000000000000000, 3)
```

But this:

```py
len(range(3, 100000000000000000000, 3))
```

returns this error:

```py
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan to have a plethora of lazily-iterable types with massive capacities, you could special-case `range` and do the math yourself:

```
def robustish_len(c):
    try:
        return len(c)
    except OverflowError:
        return (c.stop - c.start + c.step - 1) // c.step
```

Or, alternatively:

```
def robust_len(c):
    try:
        return len(c)
    except OverflowError:
        return float('inf')  # close enough  :)
```

Comment: Note that this only works if `c.stop` is greater than `c.start`.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a bug in Python. At least for classes, you could replace

> len(c)

with

> `c.__len__()`

Comment: This is not a bug but explicitly documented, *intentional* behaviour to make the result fit into the C type ``Py_ssize_t``. [According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), ``__len__`` has the same restriction as ``len`` – it is merely not enforced for fully user-defined types. ``range(sys.maxsize + 1).__len__()`` results in the same error as ``len(range(sys.maxsize + 1))``.

Comment: Just because it is documented doesn't make it not a bug. Is there actually a reason for not allowing len to return an arbitrary int? This seems like a needless restriction on classes.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason as mentioned: to fit into `Py_ssize_t`, or in other words for each element to be addressable. The size is enough for about 8EiB (if each element were just 1B) or 300 years of iteration (if each step took just 1ns). There is practically nothing which is both that large and simultaneously still a single container.

Comment: You're assuming that all the elements actually exist. But in a class, elements can exist virtually until they are needed, and become virtual again when they are no longer needed. This limit seems like an unnecessary restriction. It's not as if the length needs to be stored anywhere, and, in fact, might be quite dynamic. And addressability isn't an issue--think of dicts for example.

Comment: And, by the way, the documentation says nothing about what `__len__` can return.

Comment: Addressability means that the hardware can address it: `Py_ssize_t` is defined in terms of the architecture pointer size (e.g. 64bit on a 64bit machine). How some high-level data structure such as `dict` represents access is inconsequential. Even for types that lazily create elements, this size is more than sufficient because a larger object cannot practically be worked with ever (see above on how long it would take to use such an object fully). There is just no *practical* use to have a non-native size type.

Comment: The documentation for `__len__` linked above states “the length is required to be at most `sys.maxsize`”. Yes, in principle `__len__` can return a larger value, just like it could return a float, string, `dict` or anything else; all of these violate the specification.

Comment: To quote the documentation:
 [`__len__`] Called to implement the built-in function len(). Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0.
CPython implementation detail: In CPython, the length is required to be at most sys.maxsize. If the length is larger than sys.maxsize some features (such as len()) may raise OverflowError. 
So this isn't a Python issue, but a CPython implementation deficiency.

Comment: "There is just no practical use to have a non-native size type." That's the sort of thing that was said about number theory, and yet, it is an integral part of the Internet today. I wouldn't be bothering with this if I didn't have a practical use. But, as I said, I can work around this limit by calling `__len__` instead of using `len`, and the documentation I quoted says that it is fine to have `__len__` return any integer >= 0 as long as I can live with CPython possibly getting an OverflowError when calling `len`. I still think this is a fixable bug in the CPython implementation.

Comment: You are of course free to reject the background information in my comments. That does not change that in the primary Python implementation which restricts `len` with an upper bound, a compliant `__len__` has the same restriction and is thus not a suitable alternative. Doubly so for the situation presented in the question.

Comment: I do appreciate your comments; they're very helpful to understand the issues. The question gave the `range` example, but was phrased more generally, and I was responding to that, as well as my own experience running into this issue for a `class` I've implemented (which is how I landed at the question in the first place). I don't know all the underlying implementation issues, but I find it hard to believe that the restriction couldn't be lifted without impacting performance. In fact, converting a class's `__len__` output to a C int and then back again as a `len` result must cost something.